# Django many to many doesn't work in unittest but works in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-1.8

I have two models related through a Many-to-many field.

```
class Tires(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tires = models.ManyToManyField('Tires', blank=True)
```

It works fine when I add tires to a car through the admin page, but it does not work in my unittests and I can't figure out what the problem is (probably something really simple)

This is my unittest:

```
def test_many_to_many(self):
    tires_1 = Tires(brand='bridgestone')
    tires_1.save()
    car_1 = Car(brand='BMW')
    car_1.save()
    car_1.tires.add(tires_1)
    car_1.save()
```

This doesn't raise any exceptions, but when I print car_1.tires, it says *carthings.Tires.None*
I've tried it the other way around, adding car_1  to tires_1.car_set but that gives the same result. I've also tried adding an object of a different class in the many-to-many field just to see what would happen, that does raise an error. So it looks like the adding works but it just doesn't save or something?

Comment: Put Bridgestone between apostrophes.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I will edit that in, it's not the problem but I modified my model a little to show it here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably doing this:

```
>> print car_1.tires
carthings.tires.None
```

Which is a representation of the "related objects manager".
You probably want to do something like:

```
>> print car_1.tires.all()
[<Tire 1>]
```

Which returns a queryset, and its representation is more meaningful, since it actually performs a query to show the first elements in the relationship.

By the way, you don't need to `save` the model after adding something to the tires relationship, since you don't need to update the Cars table.